# CMake - Copy specific files in custom target

Tags: c++, cmake, copy

i want to copy specific files for code coverage from sub directories, which are generated during the build process via custom target.
Is there a possibility, to do a recursive copy via `add_custom_target` and `COMMAND`, e.g.:

```
add_custom_target(copyFiles
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy **/*.gcda ./
  DEPENDS ${TARGET_NAME}
)
```

Comment: Can you explain what you're actually trying to do or produce a minimal reproducible example that mimics the behavior you _have_ in order to explain the behavior you'd _like to observe_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your custom target may run a CMake script (e.g., `${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P find_and_copy.cmake`) which is going to perform `file(GLOB_RECURSE...)` and then do `file(COPY...)` on found files.

Comment: Thank you very much